# How to make the absolute child width independent from the relative parent width?

Tags: css, width, css-position

I need to realize this menu with its submenu:

[image]

I set the main menu to be a `ul`/`li` with `li` `float: left; display: block;` and inside them there is an a element with properties `display: block;` and some padding.

Every `li` has `position: relative`. Inside every `li` there is a `.main_menu_submenu` div, with `position: absolute`. Inside, it has another `ul`/`li` where every `li` has again properties `display: block; float: left`.
The problem is that the width of `.main_menu_submenu` adapts depending on the width of the container `li` (of the main menu) and the submenu elements can't stay all on the same line.

This is the result:

[image]
 <sub>(source: [blueday.it](http://newsletter.blueday.it/stackov_1.png))</sub>

I tried even with `display: inline-block` instead of floating the `li`s, or putting display: inline-block to the `.main_menu_submenu` block. There is no way to make the `.main_menu_submenu` `div` stay on one single line with its width not depending from the parent li width.

If I assign `position: relative` instead of `absolute` to `.main_menu_submenu`, the result is that the parent width adapts on the child width:

[image]  <sub>(source: [blueday.it](http://newsletter.blueday.it/stackov_2.png))</sub>

I thought the only solution would be to build the submenu as a table of one row and n cells instead of a list, but I really don't like this solution.

Is there any other way to achieve the result?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/STfGL

```css
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Hide these rules from IE-mac \*/

* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
}

li.clearfix {
  display: list-item;
}

#top_header_menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent none;
  height: 70px;
}

#main_menu_cage {
  width: 100%;
  background: none #E9E9E9;
}

#main_menu_cage,
#main_menu li {
  height: 50px;
}

#main_menu_shadower_top {
  background: transparent url('/images/shadow_bg_up.png') center top no-repeat;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main_menu_shadower_bottom {
  background: transparent url('/images/shadow_bg_down.png') center bottom no-repeat;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}

#main_menu {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main_menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: #255B9A;
}

#main_menu li:hover {
  background: none #6092BB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main_menu li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px 6px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main_menu li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

#main_menu li a span {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: block;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px;
  background: none #A2C9E9;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #255B9A;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu li:hover {
  background: none transparent;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: #255B9A;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#main_menu .main_menu_submenu li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #6092BB none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="top_header_menu">
  <div id="main_menu_shadower_top"></div>

  <div id="main_menu_cage">
    <div id="main_menu" class="contents_cager">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li>
          <a href="/page/lazienda.html">
       L'Azienda
       <span>Scopri Blue Day srl</span>
      </a>
          <div class="main_menu_submenu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
              <li>
                <a href="/">La storia</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/">Le persone</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main_menu_shadower_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

(I used two `div`s (`#main_menu_shadower_bottom` and `#main_menu_shadower_top)` for the top and bottom shadow because the shadow is rounded and the bottom one has to be on top of submenu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the `position:relative;` of #main_menu li

http://jsfiddle.net/STfGL/4/

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Just wondering: why is the absolute positioned submenu staying "inside" the main_menu li which is no longer relative positioned?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**add one class as like this**

**Css**

```
.submenu{display:inline-block;}
```

**your nav code**

```
<div class="main_menu_submenu">
<ul class="submenu"> //---------------- Remove clearfix class and add submenu class this ul
<li>
<a href="/">La storia</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/">Le persone</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/STfGL/1/)**

Comment: I see no difference in your fiddle comparing to mine.